# Upgrade 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2 - ./mage conflicts and other issues

Tags: magento-1.9, error, upgrade

I tried for an hours, but i can't find the solution. Some of the file upgrade show's error. Please suggest me.

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.0.1
>   Package community/Lib_Credis 1.9.2.2 conflicts with: community/Cm_RedisSession 1.8.0.0, community/Lib_Cm 1.8.0.0, community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.0.1

Comment: No one know the answer for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like one of those goofy chicken/egg problems Magento Connect GUI is always coming up with. Cm_RedisSession is not a part of 1.9.0.1, therefore it can't be upgraded, therefore Magento Connect  cannot upgrade it.

The cure is to do it through Magento ssh command line use of Connect with the following command:

```
./mage upgrade-all --force
```

And do it two or three times as it's known to time-out or do partial upgrades, missing a package here or there or miss upgrading a file here and there. It can be beautifully spotty that way.

Back up your database, your complete Magento application before playing with Magento Connect, it is truly one of the best ways of completely taking your live e-commerce website offline.

Or learn how to untar the install archive and do it manually for a complete file replacement upgrade without the coughing hacked half-hearted installs that Magento Connect is known so well for doing.

Comment: Adding: You might need to first change the file permissions.
chmod 550 ./mage

Answer (score 1):

I had the same sort of problem upgrading from 1.6.x tot 1.8.x. It even screwed up my whole shop. Since then I never used connect manager again. Only FTP.

You can upload all your files via FTP (Make back-up and test first) That will ensure all the files have replaced your old ones

Comment: I  tried the magento version, it's working and modules updating is not working.